# How convert a Multidimensional array into one-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have array in this Format:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [PRODUCT_ID] => 40 ) [1] => Array ( [QUANTITY] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [PIECE_BAG] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [TOTAL_QUANTITY] => 2 ) [4] => Array ( [UNIT_PRICE] => 3 ) [5] => Array ( [TOTAL_PRICE] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [AVAILABILITY] => 4 ) )
```

And I want:

```
Array (  [PRODUCT_ID] => 40 [QUANTITY] => 2)
```

Comment: you got some advance with your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need iterate first by `$array[0]`, `$array[1]` and get the value that you need in a `foreach` loop. See the code:

```
<?php
$array = Array (
 0 => Array ( 'PRODUCT_ID' => 40 ),
 1 => Array ( 'QUANTITY' => 2 ),
 2 => Array ( 'PIECE_BAG' => 3 ),
 3 => Array ( 'TOTAL_QUANTITY' => 2 ),
 4 => Array ( 'UNIT_PRICE' => 3 ),
 5 => Array ( 'TOTAL_PRICE' => 6 ),
 6 => Array ( 'AVAILABILITY' => 4 ) );

$new_array = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
  foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[$key] = $value;
  }  
} 

print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [PRODUCT_ID] => 40
    [QUANTITY] => 2
)
```